# graph-api: Adaptive card with mention doesn't render date properly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

It seams that **msteams** object doesn't allow to render date, when card pushed through *graph api* in private *msteams* channel.

Example is like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages
{
  "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<attachment id=\"1\"/>"
  },
    "attachments":[
        {
            "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "id":"1",
            "content":"{\"type\":\"AdaptiveCard\",\"body\":[{\"text\":\"<at>Lev</at> hello {{ DATE(2021-04-28T00:00:00Z, SHORT) }}\",\"wrap\":true,\"type\":\"TextBlock\"}],\"version\":\"1.3\",\"msteams\":{\"entities\":[{\"type\":\"mention\",\"text\":\"<at>Lev</at>\",\"mentioned\":{\"id\":\"29:131...Rg\",\"name\":\"Lev\"}}]}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Example in teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIbta.png)

Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msteams object is not allowed through Graph API. Only Bots have access to the msteams object. This is by design.
The at mention object when you send from bot, the user will get notify in teams activity and the card will display as shown in below image

[image]

and the at mention in adaptive card using graph api post request, the user will not get notify in teams activity and the card will display as shown in below image
[image]

Comment: It's strange that without date pattern msteams object works. Ok thank you. Will try to use `mentions` objects.

Comment: @AnatoliyBotov I have updated my answer with clear explanation please check .

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below request body

```
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<attachment id=\"1\"/>"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "id": "1",
            "content": "{    \"$schema\": \"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json\",    \"type\": \"AdaptiveCard\",    \"version\": \"1.0\",    \"body\": [        {            \"type\": \"TextBlock\",            \"text\": \"Your package will arrive on {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:00:00Z, SHORT)}} at {{TIME(2017-02-14T06:00:00Z)}}\",            \"wrap\": true        }    ]}"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You missed important part of message ` msteams: `. I think because of it, render cannot show date properly. I've added `$schema` and `version 1.0`, seems no luck.

Comment: When i remove `msteams`, date rendered as expected.

Comment: @AnatoliyBotov  I am able to repro the issue. I will raise a bug if it gets confirmed from internal team.